# Why does slf4j-api 1.7.10 not work with slf4j-log4j12 1.7.10 at runtime?

Tags: logging, slf4j, noclassdeffounderror

When ever i specify these 2 dependencies on the class path , it will fail with:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory"

Anyone know about this  ?

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Declaring a dependency in maven doesn't nesessary mean that you run your application with the correct classpath. Please check how it runs and make sure all libraries are available during runtime.

Comment: BTW, `NoClassDefFoundError` usually means that the class failed to initialize earlier, so it could be not the first exception. Do you jave log4j dep too?

Comment: @kan, i could see those 2 jars on the output of System.getProperties("java.class.path").

Comment: Do you jave log4j dep too?

Comment: Please make sure you understand difference between ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError.